# obj[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) does not get called if hint is string

Tags: javascript

I have this code bellow :

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  money: 1000,

  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    console.log(`hint: ${hint}`);
    return hint == "string" ? `{name: "${this.name}"}` : this.money;
  },
};

console.log(user);
```

When I try to log the object to the console  `console.log(user);` I get this

```
Object { name: "John", money: 1000, Symbol("Symbol.toPrimitive"): Symbol.toPrimitive(hint) }
```

But I expect the result to be something like this :

```
hint: string -> {name: "John"}
```

and when i use `alert(user)` i get the expected behavior

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Logging an *object* doesn't convert it to a primitive. It's very easy to see - log any object and you'll see it's not an integer nor a string nor a boolean.

Comment: Try to log `String(user)` or `+user` and it'll work fine.

Comment: try `console.log(String(user));` and `console.log(user + 1);`

Comment: @VLAZ when i use alert(user) i get "hint: string -> {name: "John"}" what's the difference here between console.log and alert ? i'm sorry i'm very new to js

Comment: @lzaek `alert()` only shows text. So it will convert any object to a string. Hence why if you do `alert({foo: 1})` you'll actually see `[object Object]` in the popup.

Comment: `console.log()` behavior is more complicated then `alert()` — it tries its best to serialize objects in details.